# Change image on button click in p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I have 2 dimensional array filled with cells. i want this cell to update image on button press. I want to pass the value to the constructor but something goes wrong and its nowt working.my thought was to pass to constructor image value this.img = img then in show_cell function change image value to this.img value. when i press button it start function wher i add image to constructor and show grid. non of this is working. Please help, it give me a headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to draw the grid in [`draw()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/draw). Note, `draw()` is continuously called by the system and redraws the entire window, it is the application loop. At the begin of `draw` You've to set the background color ([`background()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/background)), then you've to draw the entire scene.

Set a state variable (`show_grid`) when the button is pressed:

```js
let show_grid = false;
function a(){
    show_grid = true;
}
```

Draw the grid dependent on the the state of the variable:

```js
function draw() {

    background(255);

    if (show_grid) {
        grid.display();
    }

    fill(255);
    stroke(0);
    let fps = frameRate();
    text("FPS: " + fps.toFixed(0), 10, height - 10);
}
```

If you want to change the images on a click to a button, then you`ve to use a variable (e.g`current_img`) wihich is used to draw the cells:

```js
class Cell {
    constructor (column, row, size) {
        this.x = column;
        this.y = row;
        this.w = size;
    }
    show_cell () {
        image(current_img, this.x * this.w , this.y * this.w , this.w , this.w );
    }
}
```

When a button is clicked, then the `current_image` has to be changed:

```js
function a(){
    show_grid = true;
    current_img = img1;
}

function b(){
    show_grid = true;
    current_img = img2;
}
```

See the example:

```js
var grid;
var current_img;
var img1;
var img2;
function preload(){
  img1 = loadImage('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/resource/texture/fish64.png');
  img2 = loadImage('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/resource/texture/ball64.png');
}

function setup() {
    const background_btn1 = select('#BgCategory1-btn1');
    background_btn1.mousePressed(a);
    const background_btn2 = select('#BgCategory1-btn2');
    background_btn2.mousePressed(b);
    let cnv = createCanvas(1000, 1000);
    cnv.parent('canvas-holder');
    grid = new Grid(40);
    current_img = img1;
} 

function draw() {
    background(128);
  
    if (show_grid) {
        grid.display();
    }

    fill(255);
    stroke(0);
    let fps = frameRate();
    text("FPS: " + fps.toFixed(0), 10, 30);
}

let show_grid = false;

function a(){
    show_grid = true;
    current_img = img1;
}

function b(){
    show_grid = true;
    current_img = img2;
}

class Grid {
    constructor (cellSize) {
      this.cellSize = cellSize;
      this.numberOfColumns = floor(width / this.cellSize);
      this.numberOfRows = floor(height / this.cellSize);

      this.cells = new Array(this.numberOfColumns);
      for (var column = 0; column < this.numberOfColumns; column ++) {
          this.cells[column] = new Array(this.numberOfRows);
      }

      for (var column = 0; column < this.numberOfColumns; column ++) {
          for (var row = 0; row < this.numberOfRows; row++) {
              this.cells[column][row] = new Cell(column, row, cellSize)  
          }
      }
    }

    display () {
        for (var column = 0; column < this.numberOfColumns; column ++) {
            for (var row = 0; row < this.numberOfRows; row++) {
                this.cells[column][row].show_cell();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Cell {
    constructor (column, row, size) {
        this.x = column;
        this.y = row;
        this.w = size;
    }
    show_cell () {
        image(current_img, this.x * this.w , this.y * this.w , this.w , this.w );
    }
}
```

```css
#BgCategory1-btn1 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
#BgCategory1-btn2 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 10%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
<button id= "BgCategory1-btn1" >image 1</button>
<button id= "BgCategory1-btn2" >image 2</button>
<div id = "canvas-holder"></div>
```